# Regular expression not working in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, security, .htaccess, web-hosting

I'm trying to limit which characters can be used in the request URI using:

`RewriteEngine on`

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([a-z0-9:/\.\_\-]) [NC]

RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

For some reason it's not working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than creating that sort of filter yourself you might want to take a look at mod_security (http://www.modsecurity.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. A good way to protect against XSS (cross site scripting).

This is the solution:

```
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^a-z0-9\_\:\/\.\-] [NC]
            RewriteRule () - [F,L]
```

A shorter equivalent would be:

```
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteRule [^a-z0-9\_\:\/\.\-] - [F,L]
```